# Bug alterar posição de banners site laravel

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou desenvolvendo um site onde ele possui um modal de banners e quero definir um campo no banco de dados do tipo "ordem", onde eu possa definir qual banner aparece em primeiro, segundo, terceiro ... no meu painel administrador eu tenho uma listagem de todos os banners e o banner que está em terceiro eu preciso definir ele para primeiro, o quarto para segundo, o primeiro para terceiro, ou seja, poder alterar a ordem deles após cadastrado. Usei o código abaixo, ele funciona apenas 3 vezes e depois começa a dar bug, não funciona. Preciso muito de ajuda a fazer isso, definir ordem para eles e salvar a ordem no banco de dados.

```
private function ordenaPosicionamento($posicaoAntiga, $novaPosicao)
    {
        if($novaPosicao == 1)
        {
            // busca todos banners num array     
            $banners = Banner::where('status', '=', true)->get();

            // busca o banner para ser alterado e seta um valor temporario para alteracao     
            $bannerParaAlteracao = $banners[$posicaoAntiga - 1];
            $bannerParaAlteracao->ordem = 0;

            // sobe a posicao dos anteriores     
            for($i2 = $posicaoAntiga; $i2 < count($banners); $i2++)
            {
                $banners[$i2]->ordem = $banners[$i2]->ordem - 1;
            }

            // ajusta a posicao de todos {final}     
            for($i4 = 0; $i4 < count($banners); $i4++)
            {
                $banners[$i4]->ordem = $banners[$i4]->ordem + 1;
                //echo "NOME " . $banners[$i4]->nome . " ORDEM " . $banners[$i4]->ordem . "<br>";
                //$banners[$i4]->save();
            }

            foreach($banners as $banner)
            {
                $banner->save();
            }
        }
    }
```

meu banco de dados tem os seguintes campos: id, status, ordem, nome

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar usar Collections, talvez fique mais fácil. Veja se isso ajuda:

```
$banners = Banner::where('status', '=', true)->get()->sortBy('ordem');
$b = $banners->get($posicaoAntiga-1);
$array = $banners->forget($posicaoAntiga-1)->sortBy('ordem')->all();
array_splice( $array, $posicaoNova-1, 0, [$b] );
foreach ($array as $key => $a) {
    $a->ordem = $key+1;
    $a->save();
}
```

Neste código, a coleção de retorno é ordenada por `ordem`. Após isto, é retirado o elemento da posição antiga e a coleção é reordenada para gerar novas chaves. Então inserimos o elemento na posição nova convertendo a coleção para array com `all()` e usando array_splice. Depois é só gravar a nova ordem e salvar.

Veja se funciona para o seu caso.

Comment: Então ainda não funcionou, por exemplo, eu tenho 5 banners, preciso pegar o terceiro e definir ele pra primeiro, o código que você passou o banner quando altero no select pra 1, ele volta uma posição ...

Comment: Editei o código. Testei novamente aqui e estava contando uma posição a mais. Tente com este código que subtrai 1 das posições.

Comment: Cara não funcionou aqui, mas eu fiz de outra forma, uma gambiarra que resolve meu problema. Mesmo assim agradeço pela atenção :D

Comment: Beleza!! Que bom que deu certo!!

Comment: Posta aí pra nóis ver, mano...

Answer (score 0):

Este código funciona apenas para se for alterar um banner para a primeira posição

```
// pega o banner que queremos alterar e seta para zero
        DB::table('banners')->where('ordem', '=', $posicaoAntiga)->update(['ordem' => 0]);

        // desce a posicao dos anteriores
        for($i2 = $posicaoAntiga; $i2 <= $this->quantidadeAtivos(); $i2++)
        {
            $nova = $i2 - 1;
            DB::table('banners')->where('ordem', '=', $i2)->update(['ordem' => $nova]);
        }

        // ajusta a posicao de todos {final} 
        for($i4 = $this->quantidadeAtivos(); $i4 >= 0; $i4--)
        {
            $nova2 = $i4 + 1;
            DB::table('banners')->where('ordem', '=', $i4)->update(['ordem' => $nova2]);
        }
```

Comment: De qualquer forma precisaria que funcionasse para qualquer posição, o primeiro vira terceiro, o segundo vira primeiro, o último vira primeiro e o quarto vira última por exemplo.